# org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid JSON for array default value: "null"

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry

I am trying to use the **confluent Kafka s3 connector using confluent-4.1.1**.

s3-sink

```
"value.converter.schema.registry.url": "http://localhost:8081",
"value.converter": "io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter",
"key.converter": "org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter"
```

When I run Kafka connectors for the s3 sink, I get this error message:

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=singular-s3-sink-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask:172)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid JSON for array default value: "null"
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.defaultValueFromAvro(AvroData.java:1649)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1562)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1443)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1443)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectSchema(AvroData.java:1323)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.toConnectData(AvroData.java:1047)
        at io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter.toConnectData(AvroConverter.java:87)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:468)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:301)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:205)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:173)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:170)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My Schema contains only 1 array type field and its schema is like this

```
{"name":"item_id","type":{"type":"array","items":["null","string"]},"default":[]}
```

I am able to see the deserialized message using the kafka-avro-console-consumer command. I have seen a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51069370) but in his case, he was using Avro serializer for key also.

```
./confluent-4.1.1/bin/kafka-avro-console-consumer --topic singular_custom_postback --bootstrap-server localhost:9092  -max-messages 2

"item_id":[{"string":"15552"},{"string":"37810"},{"string":"38061"}]
"item_id":[]
```

I cannot put the entire output I get from the console consumer as it contains sensitive user information, so I have added the only array type field in my schema.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have the same errors using 5.0 S3 connect?

Comment: Can you edit your question to the output you see from the console consumer?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have added the output of the console consumer. No, I haven't tested it on 5.0 s3 connector as we are using 4.1.1 on production. Is this a version specific issue?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem as the question that you have linked to.

[In the source code](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/4.1.1-post/avro-converter/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/avro/AvroData.java#L1647), you can see this condition.

```
  case ARRAY: {
    if (!jsonValue.isArray()) {
      throw new DataException("Invalid JSON for array default value: " + jsonValue.toString());
    }
```

And the exception can be thrown when the schema type is defined in your case as `type:"array"`, but the payload itself has a `null` value (or any other value type) rather than actually an array, despite what you have defined as your schema default value. The default is only applied when the `items` element isn't there at all, not when `"items":null`

---

Other than that, I would suggest a schema like so, i.e. a record object, not just a named array, with a default of an empty array, not `null`.

```
{
  "type" : "record",
  "name" : "Items",
  "namespace" : "com.example.avro",
  "fields" : [ {
    "name" : "item_id",
    "type" : {
      "type" : "array",
      "items" : [ "null", "string" ]
    },
    "default": []
  } ]
}
```

Comment: But, we are making sure to send an empty array if the value of items is null, so "items": null can never happen

Comment: @cricket_007 I am having the same issue. I will investigate as well next week. But does anyone maybe know why the kafka-avro-console-consumer manages to deserialise what the s3 sink could not? Avro is either valid or not. Am I missing sth? thx!

Comment: @Vassilis The error is thrown in the Connect API, which the console consumer does not use

Answer (score 0):

The `io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroData.defaultValueFromAvro(AvroData.java:1649)` is called for the conversion of avro schema of the message you read to the connect sink's internal schema. I believe it is not related to the data of your message. That is why the `AbstractKafkaAvroDeserializer` can successfully deserialise your message (e.g. via `kafka-avro-console-consumer`), as your message is a valid avro message. The above exception may occur if your default value is `null`, while `null` is not a valid value of your field. E.g.

```
{
   "name":"item_id",
   "type":{
      "type":"array",
      "items":[
         "string"
      ]
   },
   "default": null
}
```

I would propose you to remotely debug connect and see what exactly is failing.